# SCSS Mixin issue due to use

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins, dart-sass

I have a file called `_mixins.scss`. I `@use` it in a file called `_index.scss` along with my other partials. I `@forward` all of these in my `home.scss` file.

The contents of `_mixins.scss` are

```
@mixin flexCenter($flex-direction){
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    flex-direction:$flex-direction;
    // If height is required, add manually
}
```

The contents of `_index.scss` are

```
@use 'resets' as *;
@use 'fonts' as *;
@use 'mixins' as *;
```

(All files paths are correct)

```
@forward '../'; // imports all the styles from index.scss
// @import '../mixins';

.landing-section{
    @include flexCenter(row);

    height:100vh;
}
```

However when I try to use my mixin, I get an error.

```
Error: Undefined mixin.
@include flexCenter(row);
```

My folder structure is

```
scss/home
```

`_mixins.scss` and `_index.scss` are in the scss directory while `home.scss` is in the home directory.

Funnily enough, when I use the old deprecated `@import`, my mixin works.
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I think you want to forward the mixin file, not @use. Use is used in the actual file where you put the mixin in your code

Comment: Hi there! Yes indeed, that was the issue.